# Google AppEngine 'rdbms API is not available' on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

```
python 
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
```

everything's smooth on the command line but i still get the following in the appengine log

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --admin_console_server= --port=8080
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2012-08-03 14:15:31,002 py_zipimport.py:148] zipimporter('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg', 'MySQLdb/')
WARNING  2012-08-03 14:15:31,096 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
WARNING  2012-08-03 14:15:31,183 datastore_file_stub.py:518] Could not read datastore data from /var/folders/mc/45jr0vk5217fmpl18jn3vgx40000gn/T/dev_appserver.datastore
WARNING  2012-08-03 14:15:31,188 dev_appserver.py:3498] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
INFO     2012-08-03 14:15:31,194 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:647] Running application dev~appexp87 on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-08-03 14:15:31,194 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:649] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use CloudSQL?  If not, don't worry about the rdbms API warning, that line is harmless.  So is the PIL warning.

You shouldn't get that warning about not being able to read the datastore file though.  It might be a matter of file permissions, or perhaps the file somehow got corrupted.  If they data's not necessary, try clearing out the datastore file and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line `import MySQLdb` to the `dev_appserver.py` file, if you have not already done so.